# unable to find Graphical MDX Query Designer - Cube is generated by Dynamics AX

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, dynamics-ax-2009, bids, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to BI. I am slicing and Dicing the data in BIDS browser. Now i want to generate a MDX query from the data which i am slicing and dicing.

Is a tool available to that in SQL server analysis service ?

Update : I am not seeing any designer button ?

[image]

[image]

Cube is generated by dynamics ax
I tried to open the query designer from report builder and i getting the following error :

Comment: Graphical MDX Query Designer in Query Mode I cant find it  ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403829.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the query designer click on this button after graphically designing your query and it should automatically generate your mdx.

[image]

Once you are out of the GUI mode you can also write your mdx in there.

Comment: I am not seeing the designer button.

Comment: Which version are you using? 08 05?

Comment: Due to it being Microsoft product, guessing you need to right click and add a toolbar or something of that nature.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Which version of SQL server you are using ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9518/discussion-between-gainster-and-user-smith)

Comment: I am on 2012, sorry I had to run.

Comment: I am guessing in 2008 you may not have access to that mode.  You may need to be in the cube itself not in the bids browser.  You could connect via excel powerpivot.  I know that you can reach the non gui designer from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have version 17.2 and there is a bug in the query edit in MDX. Buttons are un proper. The button with the red square meaning "STOP" is actually the design view of the query! So, try clicking on the stop button and see if it works for you! If it does, you will go in design view instead of stoping your query!